# Do we need to republish the application on google marketplace after changing the support page in manifest file?

Tags: manifest, google-apps-marketplace

I've an application published on Google Marketplace which has a support page URL in its manifest file.
Do I need to republish the application after changing that support page URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your App is Once approved in google apps marketplace and if you are making some changes to the listing just saving it would make the changes affected.

But if your app isn't approved yet, you need to submit it again. So that Google marketplace team would be aware of the changes.